# TreeView folder structure with a exception

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, treeview

I have two `TreeViews` and each of them generate a folder structure on a Drive.
The program only has 1 `comboBox` to build both `TreeViews` in 2 drives.
I only use one `comboBox` because almost every folder has the same name on `F:` and `Z:`

I say almost because I have 3 folders which have similair names but not the exact.

So let's say my DropDown looks like this:

```
Book1
Book2
Book3
Book4
```

So the dirs on Z: look like the example above, because that's the Source of my `comboBox`

And R: looks like this:

```
Book1
Book2
Book3_projects_render
Book4
```

So my Code works for Book1, Book2 and Book4 but when I click on Book3 on my DropDown and create my TreeView structure, it will create a new dir on R: named Book3 and the solution I want to achieve, is to make exceptions for dirs like `Book3_projects_render` so it won't make a new dir.

**My Code:**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // ...

    loremDropDown.DisplayMember = "Name";
    loremDropDown.ValueMember = "FullName";
    loremDropDown.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo("F:\\").GetDirectories();
}

private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var driveF = "F:\\";
    var driveZ = "Z:\\";
    var selDir = loremDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    var destPathF = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveF);
    var destPathZ = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveZ);
    var treeSep = pathLorem.PathSeparator;
    var dirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    var shortcuts = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(pathLorem.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathF, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);

        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveF.ToArray()));
    }

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(ipsumPath.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathZ, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);

        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveZ.ToArray()));
    }

    foreach (var shortcut in shortcuts)
    {
        var dirF = $"{driveF}{shortcut}";
        var dirZ = $"{driveZ}{shortcut}";

        if (Directory.Exists(dirF) && Directory.Exists(dirZ))
        {
            CreateShortcut(dirF, dirZ);
            CreateShortcut(dirZ, dirF);
        }
    }
}

private void CreateShortcut(string shortcutPath, string targetPath)
{
    WshShell wshShell = new WshShell();
    string fileName = Path.Combine(shortcutPath, $"{Application.ProductName}.lnk");
    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(fileName);
    shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

Comment: You mean that you want to select a name that is applied as-is in one *entity* but eventually in a different way in another *entity*? You can build a map object, as a `Dictionary<string, string>`. When you have a selection, you check whether the Dictionary contains that key: if it doesn't, apply the selection, otherwise get the corresponding Value. It's easy to maintain, should the dualism extend further.

Comment: Why don't just rename the folders nodes in both tree views to create dirs with the same names? What is the catch or the rule here? If the folder names are identical in both drives, then make them identical. Also, a suggestion based on the last problems. Wouldn't be easier if you use just one `TreeView` control and have a `Root` node for each drive? A root `F:` node has its own Books, Book1, Book2. Papers, Paper 1, Paper 2...etc child nodes... Same thing for `Z:`. Keep it simple.

Comment: I have 3D files which have dedicated folders in the files, so i can't rename anything. And I think you misunderstood. Yes every folder have the same name except 3 folders which don't have the same name. So everything is working except 3 folders which have similair but not the same name. Like: "Book1" folder is named "Book_1_doc_files" in the other Drive.

Comment: And i am speaking of the folders which the user can choose from in the comboBox

Comment: OK understood, I take it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rename the TreeNode objects Before creating the Directories**

Here's a way to rename given folders based on [Jimi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) suggestion.

- Create a `Dictionary<string, string>` to have the target folders as keys and the new names as values.
- For each `TreeView` control, clone its nodes in a temp `TreeView` to change the `.Text` properties of the target nodes without reflecting that on the main `TreeView` controls. Setting the `.Text` property is necessary to get the correct `.FullPath` property when you rename a parent and/or child node.

```cs
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var driveF = "C:\\";
    var driveZ = "D:\\";
    var selDir = loremDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    var destPathF = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveF);
    var destPathZ = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveZ);
    var treeSep = pathLorem.PathSeparator;
    var dirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    var shortcuts = new HashSet<string>();
    var dirsToRename = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Book 4", "Book 1" },
        { "Book 5", "Book 2" },
        { "Book 6", "Book 3" },
        { "Books", "Books 123" }
    };

    using (var tv = new TreeView())
    {
        tv.Nodes.AddRange(pathLorem.Nodes
            .OfType<TreeNode>()
            .Select(n => n.Clone() as TreeNode)
            .ToArray());

        foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(tv.Nodes))
        {
            if (dirsToRename.ContainsKey(node.Text)) node.Text = dirsToRename[node.Text];
            var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathF, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
            if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveF.ToArray()));
        }

        tv.Nodes.Clear();
        tv.Nodes.AddRange(ipsumPath.Nodes
            .OfType<TreeNode>()
            .Select(n => n.Clone() as TreeNode)
            .ToArray());

        foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(tv.Nodes))
        {
            if (dirsToRename.ContainsKey(node.Text)) node.Text = dirsToRename[node.Text];
            var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathZ, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
            if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveZ.ToArray()));
        }

        foreach (var shortcut in shortcuts)
        {
            var dirF = $"{driveF}{shortcut}";
            var dirZ = $"{driveZ}{shortcut}";

            if (Directory.Exists(dirF) && Directory.Exists(dirZ))
            {
                CreateShortcut(dirF, dirZ);
                CreateShortcut(dirZ, dirF);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Rename given TreeNode objects based on destinations**

The keys are taken from the `ComboBox` control.

```cs
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var driveF = "C:\\";
    var driveZ = "D:\\";
    var selDir = loremDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    var destPathF = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveF);
    var destPathZ = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveZ);
    var treeSep = pathLorem.PathSeparator;
    var dirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    var shortcuts = new HashSet<string>();
    var dirsToRename = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Book 1", "Book 4" },
        { "Book 2", "Book 5" },
        { "Book 3", "Book 6" }
    };

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(pathLorem.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathF, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));

        // Comment this if `pathLorem` is not the source of the keys...
        if (dirsToRename.ContainsKey(node.Text))
            sPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath), dirsToRename[node.Text]);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);

        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveF.ToArray()));
    }

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(ipsumPath.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathZ, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));

        // Comment this if `ipsumPath` is not the source of the keys...
        if (dirsToRename.ContainsKey(node.Text))
            sPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath), dirsToRename[node.Text]);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);

        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.TrimStart(driveZ.ToArray()));
    }

    foreach (var shortcut in shortcuts)
    {
        var dirF = $"{driveF}{shortcut}";
        var dirZ = $"{driveZ}{shortcut}";

        if (Directory.Exists(dirF) && Directory.Exists(dirZ))
        {
            CreateShortcut(dirF, dirZ);
            CreateShortcut(dirZ, dirF);
        }
    }
}
```

You can add a control such as `DataGridView` to get the key-value pairs of the `dirsToRename` dictionary instead of the hard-code.

**Rename a Directory after creating it**

You can rename a system file or directory by calling the `.Move` method of the [`File`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) and [`Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-6.0) classes respectively.

```cs
// Rename a file...
File.Move("source", "destination");

// Rename a directory...
Directory.Move("source", "destination");
```

**Map a selected Directory to another**

To map a selected directory from the `ComboBox` to another directory, change `destPathF` or `destPathZ` (not both) depending on the location of the target (`Book3_projects_render` for example) directory.

For example:

```cs
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var driveF = "C:\\";
    var driveZ = "D:\\";
    var selDirInfo = loremDropDown.SelectedItem as DirectoryInfo;
    var selDir = selDirInfo.FullName;
    var destPathF = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveF);
    var destPathZ = selDir.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(selDir), driveZ);
    var treeSep = pathLorem.PathSeparator;
    var dirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    var shortcuts = new HashSet<string>();
    var exDir = "Book 3";
    var repDir = "Book3_projects_render";
    bool isExDir = selDirInfo.Name == exDir;

    if (isExDir)
    {
        // If `Book3_projects_render` is on F: otherwise comment...
        //destPathF = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPathF), "Book3_projects_render");

        // If `Book3_projects_render` is on Z: otherwise comment...
        destPathZ = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPathZ), repDir);
    }

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(pathLorem.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathF, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.Substring(driveF.Length));
    }

    foreach (var node in GetCheckedNodes(ipsumPath.Nodes))
    {
        var sPath = Path.Combine(destPathZ, node.FullPath.Replace(treeSep, dirSep));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
        if (node.Level == 0) shortcuts.Add(sPath.Substring(driveZ.Length));
    }

    foreach (var shortcut in shortcuts)
    {
        var dirF = $"{driveF}{shortcut}";
        var dirZ = $"{driveZ}{shortcut}";

        if (isExDir)
        {
            // If `Book3_projects_render` is on Z: otherwise switch exDir and repDir...
            dirF = dirF.Replace($@"\{repDir}\", $@"\{exDir}\");
            dirZ = dirZ.Replace($@"\{exDir}\", $@"\{repDir}\");
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(dirF) && Directory.Exists(dirZ))
        {
            CreateShortcut(dirF, dirZ);
            CreateShortcut(dirZ, dirF);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll get  -> CS0104: "TreeView"  is an ambiguous reference between "System.Windows.Forms.TreeView" and "System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TreeView".

Comment: When I change ->  using (var tv = new TreeView()) to ->  using (var tv = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView()) I don't get any Errors but the Code is not making exceptions. So it works like it worked before the change.

Comment: well I guess we have different timezones or you like your coffee at midnight :D unfortunately both new solutions didn't work out, I tried different variations to make sure I didn't miss a thing :/

Comment: I edited my question, I hope I could clarify my Issue better. I will not give up Mr. Null as long as I have some nice people like you on SO.

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle Does adding a first line `if (node.Text == "Book3") continue;` in the loops make any difference?

Comment: Its not the nodes I am trying to change -  but I get what I did wrong in my question. I used Book as an example for my dirs and my TreeView nodes. I don't want to make a exception depending on my TreeView. It's all about my Drive files which I can choose from in my comboBox. So everything in my TreeView is fine - I want to add Exceptions depending on the dir chosen in my comboBox.

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle Just a quick question. Do you need to create the structure in `Book3_projects_render` for example **when** you choose `Book3` for example from the dropdown? So, instead of creating the dirs in a new folder `Book3`, create then in `Book3_projects_render` which is supposed to be the twin dir. Right? Wrong?

Comment: YES! exactly :D

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle Try to see if we get any closer...

Comment: it works dr.null it works! but the shortcuts dont work with book3_projects_render but with the normal ones shortcuts work

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle True, this new condition turned the logic upside down. We need to do the same for the shortcuts. Fixed now using a 50cent solution until maybe a better way pops up. Please note, the whole thing needs a serious redesign.

Comment: Yea, but now at least I have one exception :D Thank you

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle Since I don't know what's the project's scope nor what do you have from here. Consider these improvement/redesign suggestions. 1) When the app starts, read the target system dirs to populate the `TreeView` controls. 2) Create the directories as you add new `TreeNode` objects. 3) Use the `TreeNode` check boxes in the `TreeView` controls to map the twins dirs, so when you add a new node in a checked node, the code adds another in its twin. 4) This way, you don't need to have the `ComboBox` nor a Button click to create the dirs and shortcuts. It will be a synchronized edit.

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestions, but my TreeView/TreeNodes don't have anything to do with my comboBox and the dirs or the twins. Imagine Drive R: and Z: having random files like: Ubisoft, Epic Games etc. and this is the content I can pick from my comboBox and my TreeView contains: 3D, Audio, Max files etc. so my TreeView content will always be the same structure. My issue was that some folders on R: have names like Ubisoft_projects.

Comment: The purpose is to make it easier to create a folder structure for a new project because It's always the same and It makes my life much easier to click on that button rather than copy pasting my template folders and create shortcuts all the time. Your solution is already perfect - Yes maybe the version - where the shortcuts didn't work - looked better in Code but the current solution does the whole Job :) I only have 3 folders which  don't have the exact same name so it's just a few vars more in the Code but it does the Job :D You saved a young man some time

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle Very well then. God bless and good luck.

Comment: you too man, you too <3